# PhoneRTC Swift update causes no audio on ios

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova, phonertc

I've built iOS and Android versions of the PhoneRTC project. 1 Android device (KitKat 4.4) and 1 iOS device (iphone 4, iOS 7.1). Both connected to private lan 192.168.1.x. Also, tried TURN server and confirmed successful TURN server messages in server log.

After fixing Swift compile errors on iOS (NSURL and Regex). All compiles and seems to work without throwing errors. Here's my problem and humbly ask for someone's help.

1. Audio comes through Android just fine, sounds great. So, iOS microphone records/sends audio successfully to Android and is rendered to Android speaker.
2. Android permission for the microphone is enabled, however the sounds does not arrive on the iOS side. Nothing is heard on the speaker.

Am I missing something here?

Update: I've confirmed that it is the Android library not sending the microphone audio. iOS to browser works fine. Will add issue to Github.

Cheers.
Rich

Answer (score 2):

The issue was fixed in this commit:
https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc/commit/8bf270014cdfe6acc6d2cb9aeee624c2d9e39536